# Duda Select SQL

Tags: sql

Soy nuevo aqui. No soy  muy ducho en SQL. Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar

Quiero hacer una consulta a una misma columna (star_result) pero separar los resultados dependiendo de que la columna rating_item_id tenga un valor 2 (Importancia) o 3 (Urgencia)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT star_result AS Importancia,star_result AS Urgencia
FROM ycdxw_mrp_rating_result
WHERE rating_item_id = "2" OR rating_item_id = "3"
```

El problema es que no se cómo puedo asignar en WHERE el 2 al alias Importancia y el 3 al alias Urgencia. Me salen ambos resultados en las dos columnas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias desde ya...

Comment: qué tipo de datos tienen ambas columnas?

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y explica exactamente, con los datos que ya has mostrado, cual es el resultado de la consulta que quieres obtener

Answer (score 0):

Puede que te sirva algo como el siguiente query. Aunque sin una columna pivote, no vas a ver una tabla plana como resultado.

```
SELECT 
    Importancia = case rating_item_id when 2 then star_result else null end, 
    Urgencia  = case rating_item_id when 3 then star_result else null end
FROM ycdxw_mrp_rating_result
WHERE rating_item_id = "2" OR rating_item_id = "3"
```

Comment: Gracias, reekecast. Me tira el siguiente error: SQL Error: Unknown column 'Importancia' in 'field list'

Comment: Que motor SQL estas usando? Si es mysql entonces haz el cambio del alias: `case rating_item_id when 2 then star_result else null end As Importancia, 
    case rating_item_id when 3 then star_result else null end As Urgencia`

Comment: Es mysql. Así no tira ningún error o poniendo comillas a los alias. El problema es que no devuelve ningún resultado.

Comment: Muy extraño. Lo acabo de probar, y si lo hace. No sé que podría ser.
http://rextester.com/MVSX99811

Comment: Es que estoy usando un plugin de Wordpress (Display SQL Stats) para mostrar un gráfico en la web a partir de una query. Lo que me has pasado funciona bien en MySQL pero no con este plugin. Parece que no acepta el control de fluo Case. Ves alguna otra forma de hacerlo? Lo he intentado con UNION pero no va... SELECT ycdxw_mrp_rating_result.star_result AS Importancia
FROM ycdxw_mrp_rating_result
WHERE ycdxw_mrp_rating_result.rating_item_id = "2"
UNION
SELECT ycdxw_mrp_rating_result.star_result AS Urgencia
FROM ycdxw_mrp_rating_result
WHERE ycdxw_mrp_rating_result.rating_item_id = "3"